# Why is overview with only one level larger than original GeoTIF

Tags: gdal, gdaladdo

I have a large GeoTiff that I'm preparing for display through GeoServer. The original image has 4.9Gb and when I created an external overview with only one level (1/4 the size), using the same compression and color_space, the file size was 8.8Gb.

Shouldn't the overview be smaller?

*Update*: I ran the output from `gdaladdo` through `gdal_translate`, setting JPEG compression and YCbCr colorspace. File size went from 8.8Gb to 1.4Gb. Could it be that gdaladdo is not applying the compression? I have gdal v 1.11.3 - quite old. Will ask for our admin to update the package.

Here is the gdalinfo output of the original file:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: sul2014_rapideye_b321_2sd.tif
       sul2014_rapideye_b321_2sd.tif.aux.xml
Size is 206279, 239176
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-57.754539576021727,-22.341123027138849)
Pixel Size = (0.000048007576766,-0.000048007576766)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=YCbCr JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
  SOURCE_COLOR_SPACE=YCbCr
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -57.7545396, -22.3411230) ( 57d45'16.34"W, 22d20'28.04"S)
Lower Left  ( -57.7545396, -33.8233832) ( 57d45'16.34"W, 33d49'24.18"S)
Upper Right ( -47.8515846, -22.3411230) ( 47d51' 5.70"W, 22d20'28.04"S)
Lower Right ( -47.8515846, -33.8233832) ( 47d51' 5.70"W, 33d49'24.18"S)
Center      ( -52.8030621, -28.0822531) ( 52d48'11.02"W, 28d 4'56.11"S)
Band 1 Block=1024x1024 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=0
Band 2 Block=1024x1024 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=0
Band 3 Block=1024x1024 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=0
```

This is the gdaladdo command I used:

```
gdaladdo -r cubic -ro --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG --config PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR --config BIGTIFF_OVERVIEW YES sul2014_rapideye_b321_2sd.tif 2
```

And here is the gdalinfo for the overview image

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: sul2014_rapideye_b321_2sd.tif.ovr
Size is 103140, 119588
Coordinate System is `'
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=YCbCr JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
  SOURCE_COLOR_SPACE=YCbCr
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,119588.0)
Upper Right (103140.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (103140.0,119588.0)
Center      (51570.0,59794.0)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=0
Band 2 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=0
Band 3 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  NoData Value=0
```

Comment: That's a surprising result indeed. Your command is correct. I can only imagine that for some reason the JPEG compression of the original image is more efficient. I would test other resampling methods and report if they have an effect on the size of the ovr file.

Comment: I updated the question. If I run the overview though gdal_translate, file size decreases. I have an old gdal version installed (1.11.3). Maybe that's the problem

Comment: Interesting. Maybe the Overview compression is less efficient because of the small 128x128 Blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a well known and longstanding issue that GDAL struggles with compressions.  I've found that this is problematic especially when performing operations that change the block size of the image (such as merging, clipping, and generating overviews).  The result is the compression is applied more than once in certain areas which artificially blows up the output image size.  I've noticed that the increase in file size is worsened in tilted images.

As you discovered, the proper workaround is to use gdal_translate to properly apply the compression following the output creation.  This workaround should almost always be used whenever performing operations that change block sizes.

Given the level of documentation online discussing this problem, it is very likely that fixes were rolled out in later versions of GDAL than your current distribution.  I wouldn't be surprised if updating your GDAL version fixes some of your compression issues.